# Autenticação e redirecionamento externo para sites em wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, autenticação

Estou criando um simples sistema de login que redireciona um cliente para a sua área. Lá conterá links para os seus projetos, ou seja, ao clicar, ele será redirecionado para o seu site.

**EXEMPLO:** Eu tenho uma pasta chamada **sites_clientes** nessa hierarquia:

```
sites_clientes
       cliente_1
        -worpress1
        -worpress2
        -worpress3

       cliente_2
        -worpress1
        -worpress2
```

Todos os cliente terão acesso a `sites_clientes` **para a autenticação**.

**DÚVIDA:** Qual arquivo, da pasta raiz do **WORDPRESS**, devo utilizar condições com `$_SESSION` para a autenticação?

Comment: Você quer autenticar o usuário no wordpress?

Comment: Não. Já tenho feito externamente. A autenticação está em `sites_clientes`

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer fazer.

Comment: Você quer fazer um tipo de *Single Sign On*? O usuário logou no Wordpress principal e, quando redirecionado para outro, ele já deve estar autenticado?

Comment: @utluiz, é o seguinte: enterei em www.meusistema.com.br(NÃO É WORDPRESS), preenchi o meu usuário e senha e FUI REDIRECIONADO AO MEU www.meusistema.com.br/wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma de autenticar automaticamente um usuário no Wordpress é através do método [`wp_authenticate()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_authenticate) da API.

Quando o usuário fizer o login no site principal, você precisa dar um `include` no Wordpress e executar a chamada passando o usuário e senha do usuário no Wordpress.

Note que você precisa ter os dados dele no seu sistema principal, mas como obter isso vai depender do modo como a instalação é configurada.

Existem outras formas de obter o mesmo efeito, mas esta é a menos intrusiva. Alternativas incluem usar um [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/authentication) ou [sobrescrever o método de autenticação](http://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/7175/wordpress-replace-built-in-user-authentication).